# Trying to create a reverse proxy and app server on one machine with virtual interface

Tags: linux, reverse-proxy, linux-networking

I have a single server on which I need to replicate a two server environment for testing purposes.  One of the servers is an Apache reverse proxy and the other is an app server.

What I imagine I would do is setup Apache to use eth0 and create a virtual Ethernet interface (eth1) for the app server to use.  Then I would configure Apache to act as a reverse proxy for eth1 which should allow me to access the app side of things via the eth0 address.

Is this possible? or am I on the wrong path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do it that way: it will be difficult to assert whether your reverse proxy is actually working or whether you're hitting the final interface directly. You'll need to check the content of the data over the wire to be sure.

Why not setup a couple of VMs for this instead ?

Comment: Never considered it.. we're actually running as a VM already.  While I could request a new VM that would take forever.  Running VMs on a VM just seems.. odd?

Comment: Well, it's usually not even possible: you'd need an emulator instead of an hypervisor to do it and performances would be very bad. But maybe you can have a look at user-mode linux (http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/): it probably can help you with that.